# Removing a prefix using sed and regex

Tags: regex, sed

I’m trying to use *sed*(1) to remove all occurrences of `std::memset` and `std::memcpy` with `::memset` and `::memcpy`. I tried the following pattern but it is not working — I just get the same text back.

```
$ sed 's/std\(::\(memset|memcpy\)\)/${\1}/g'
```

Basically I want to get rid of std if followed by `::memset` or `::memcpy`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use extended regular expressions in the script by supplying the command-line option `-r` for GNU sed or `-E` for BSD systems like Mac OS.

```
linux$ sed -r 's/std(::(memset|memcpy))/\1/g' code.cpp

macos$ sed -E 's/std(::(memset|memcpy))/\1/g' code.cpp
```

Comment: The first doesn't work, and my `sed` (OS X) doesn't have -r... I'm looking for a portable solution, too.

Comment: Please try `sed 's/std\(::memset\|::memcpy\)/\1/g'`

Comment: What about only remove the `backslash(\)` before `bar(|)`.

Comment: OK, you were technically right with -r, it's just -E on BSD. Interestingly FreeBSD has -r for compatibility but OS X doesn't. :(

Answer (score 2):

OS X's `sed` is a curious beast!

This works:

```
bash-3.2$ echo '
std::memset()
std::memcpy()
' | sed -E 's/std(::(memset|memcpy))/\1/g' 

::memset()
::memcpy()
```

(Tested on Darwin Kernel Version 11.3.0: Thu Jan 12 18:47:41 PST 2012; root:xnu-1699.24.23~1/RELEASE_X86_64)

Comment: Seems normal to me. All my systems run BSD.